# chromedriver session not created from tab crashed after update chrome 70

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I update chrome to version 70 and I had an error with my selenium test. So I update my chromedriver to 2.43 (http://chromedriver.chromium.org/downloads) but I still have this error:

```
org.openqa.selenium.SessionNotCreatedException: 
session not created
from tab crashed
  (Session info: chrome=70.0.3538.102)
  (Driver info: chromedriver=2.42.591088 (7b2b2dca23cca0862f674758c9a3933e685c27d5),platform=Windows NT 6.1.7601 SP1 x86_64) (WARNING: The server did not provide any stacktrace information)
Command duration or timeout: 2.42 seconds
Build info: version: '3.14.0', revision: 'aacccce0', time: '2018-08-02T20:19:58.91Z'
System info: host: 'xxxxxxxxxx', ip: '192.168.103.01', os.name: 'Windows 7', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '6.1', java.version: '1.8.0_191'
Driver info: driver.version: ChromeDriver
```

**EDIT:**

same issue with chromedriver 2.44

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I update now my chrome and solve my problem.