# "NoSuchSessionError" encountered when running multiple scenarios using protractor+cucumber

Tags: protractor, cucumberjs

I am getting this error:

> NoSuchSessionError: This driver instance does not have a valid session ID (did you call WebDriver.quit()?) and may no longer be used.

In my test, I want to run multiple scenarios in one step file. I have read some questions/answers that I have to re-initialize my elements in step file.

When I try to run my code, I can see that the first scenario is performed and passed. But in my second scenario, I am not able to continue logging in to the page and stops after `loginPage.get_url();`

My feature file:

```
    Scenario: As an admin I should be able to go to reports

    Given Admin is in dashboard page
    When Admin goes to Income reports
    Then Admin should be able to click Download excel

    Scenario: As an admin I should be able to log out

    Given Admin goes back to dashboard page
    When Admin clicks the logout button
    Then Admin is now on login page
```

Here is my step file:

```
let chai          = require('chai');
let chaiAsPromised= require('chai-as-promised');
chai.use(chaiAsPromised);
let expect        = chai.expect;

const { Before, After } = require('cucumber');

var { setDefaultTimeout } = require('cucumber');
setDefaultTimeout(60 * 1200);


Given( 'Admin is in dashboard page', function () {
    LoginPage.click_dashboard_button();
} );

When( 'Admin goes to Income reports', function () {
    navPage.click_reports_dropdown();
    browser.sleep(1000);
    navPage.click_incomeReports();
} );

Then( 'Admin should be able to click Download excel', function () {
    incomeReportsPage.click_downloadExcelButton();
    browser.sleep(3000);
} );

Given( 'Admin go backs to dashboard page', function ( ) {
    LoginPage.click_dashboard_button(); 
});

When( 'Admin clicks the logout button', function () {
    LoginPage.click_logout_button();
});

Then( 'Admin is now on login page', function () {
    browser.driver.getTitle().then( function ( value ) {
        expect( value ).to.equal( "NAGM | Log in" );
    }); 
});
```

Here is my Page Object file:

```
exports.init = function init() {
    browser.waitForAngularEnabled( false );
}

exports.get_url = function get_url() {
    browser.get( "http://nagm.test.pl/login" );

}

exports.input_username = function input_username() {   

    usernameTextbox.clear();
    usernameTextbox.sendKeys("admin@nagm.ct");
}

exports.input_password = function input_password() { 

    passwordTextbox.clear();
    passwordTextbox.sendKeys("password");
}

exports.click_login_button = function click_login_button() {      
    loginButton.click();
}

exports.click_logout_button = function click_logout_button() {
    logoutButton.click();
}

exports.click_dashboard_button = function click_dashboard_button() {
    dashboardMenu.click();
}
```

My hooks.js:

```
Before (function (){
    browser.manage().window().maximize();
    loginPage.init();
    loginPage.get_url();
    loginPage.input_username();
    loginPage.input_password();
    loginPage.click_login_button();

 });
```

Comment: what version of driver and browser?

Comment: webdriver-manager 12.1.0 and im using chrome for now.

Comment: chromedriver 2.44

Comment: and chrome version 71?

Comment: Have you got any after hooks?

Comment: @sgrillon my chrome is version 71

Comment: @RaymondKelly no, I tried using After hook with deleteAllSessionCookies() which I think browser needs to delete the session but still don't work.

Comment: I have the same problem with java+chrome71+webdriver2.44: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53320142/chromedriver-session-not-created-from-tab-crashed-after-update-chrome-70

Comment: I'm not familiar with the syntax of chai, or cucumber so I'll share my experience with this error in Jasmine. This error means, browser has  been closed and the driver tries to interact with a session that doesn't exist anymore (closed). I had a test suit and sometimes I was getting this error in a middle of suit, (not all the time). So what happened was one of my methods did `browser.quit();` as a part of error handling. And all tests after that failed because browser was closed at the moment. So try to look for `quit()` command in your code