# SessionNotCreatedException: Message: session not created from disconnected: unable to connect to renderer with ChromeDriver 2.45 Chrome v71

Tags: python-3.x, selenium, google-chrome, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

When I'm executing this code with Selenium using Python:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
import time
driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=r'/Users/qa/Documents/Python/chromedriver')
```

The error occurred:

```
   Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/qa/Documents/Python/try.py", line 4, in <module>
    driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=r'/Users/qa/Documents/Python/chromedriver')
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/chrome/webdriver.py", line 81, in __init__
    desired_capabilities=desired_capabilities)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py", line 157, in __init__
    self.start_session(capabilities, browser_profile)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py", line 252, in start_session
    response = self.execute(Command.NEW_SESSION, parameters)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py", line 321, in execute
    self.error_handler.check_response(response)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/errorhandler.py", line 242, in check_response
    raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)
selenium.common.exceptions.SessionNotCreatedException: Message: session not created
from disconnected: unable to connect to renderer
  (Session info: chrome=71.0.3578.98)
  (Driver info: chromedriver=2.44.609545 (c2f88692e98ce7233d2df7c724465ecacfe74df5),platform=Mac OS X 10.13.6 x86_64)
```

Can someone help me? Thanks.

Comment: Update the question with the error trace logs.

Comment: Im using mac high sierra and I already tried to use 2.44 and 2.43 that are also support Chrome v71. I still have an error sir.

Comment: I got an error when I remove the executable_path parameter. 'chromedriver' executable needs to be in PATH. @DebanjanB

Comment: I was looking for the error stack trace

Comment: @DebanjanB Sorry sir. Ive already edit and add the Error Traceback

Comment: duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53320142/chromedriver-session-not-created-from-tab-crashed-after-update-chrome-70

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This error message...

```
selenium.common.exceptions.SessionNotCreatedException: Message: session not created
from disconnected: unable to connect to renderer
```

...implies that the **ChromeDriver** was unable to initiate/spawn a new **WebBrowser** i.e. **Chrome Browser** session.

You need to consider a fact:

- As you are using *Mac OS X* the *Key* `executable_path` must be supported with a *Value* as :

  ```
  '/Users/qa/Documents/Python/chromedriver'
  ```
- So line will be:

  ```
  driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path='/Users/qa/Documents/Python/chromedriver')
  ```

**Note**: The *path* itself is a raw path so you don't need to add the switch `r` and drop it.

Additionally, ensure that `/etc/hosts` on your system contains the following entry :

```
127.0.0.1 localhost.localdomain localhost
#or
127.0.0.1 localhost loopback
```

Comment: It works sir and I also edit my hosts because my localhost is blocked. Thanks

Comment: My hosts contains the config but still facing this problem. I did not know what to do to fix it .@DebanjanB https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70143701/arguments-sessionnotcreatedexceptionsession-not-created-nfrom-disconnected

Answer (score 12):

I had a similar error, first getting the error message:

> selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: unknown error: Chrome failed to start: exited normally.
> (unknown error: DevToolsActivePort file doesn't exist)

This was solved by adding `options.add_argument("--remote-debugging-port=9230")` to the ChromeOptions(). And the program runs once and I gained the same error message as above:

> selenium.common.exceptions.SessionNotCreatedException: Message: session not created
> from disconnected: unable to connect to renderer
> (Session info: headless chrome=89.0.4389.114)

The problem here was that the chrome process does not close properly in the program so the process is still active on the debugging-port. To solve this problem close the active port `sudo kill -9 $(sudo lsof -t -i:9230)` and simply add the following lines to the end of the code:

```
driver.stop_client()
driver.close()
driver.quit()
```

Since I didn't find this answer anywhere, I hope it helps someone.

Answer (score 10):

If you have **options.add_argument("--remote-debugging-port=9222")** change this to **options.add_argument("--remote-debugging-port=9230")**

or just simply Adding  **options.add_argument("--remote-debugging-port=9230")**  fixed in my case.

Comment: I do not  know why, it did not work for me. I am using a debian docker image.

Answer (score 2):

I ran into this same issue on a Windows 10 machine. What I had to do to resolve the issue was to open the Task Manager and exit all Python.exe processes, along with all Chrome.exe processes. After doing this,

Answer (score 1):

I am facing the same error and add the close code solve the problem, the code finnaly block look like this:

```
    @staticmethod
    def fetch_music_download_url(music_name: str):
        chrome_driver_service = Service(ChromeDriverManager(chrome_type=ChromeType.GOOGLE).install())
        chrome_options = Options()
        chrome_options.add_argument("--headless")
        chrome_options.add_argument("--no-sandbox")
        chrome_options.add_argument("--disable-gpu")
        chrome_options.add_argument("--remote-debugging-port=9230")
        driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=chrome_driver_service, options=chrome_options)
        try:
            driver.maximize_window()
            driver.get('http://example.cn/music/?page=audioPage&type=migu&name=' + music_name)
            driver.implicitly_wait(5)
            // do some logic
        except Exception as e:
            logger.error(e)
        finally:
            // add the close logic
            driver.stop_client()
            driver.close()
            driver.quit()
            chrome_driver_service.stop()
```

the key is you should close the chrome service after using it by add `chrome_driver_service.stop()`.hope this code could help other people facing the same issue.

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me on `WINDOWS OS`

```py
from selenium import webdriver
import time
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options

options = Options()
options.add_argument('--headless')
options.add_argument('--disable-gpu')
driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=options)
driver.get(url)
time.sleep(3)
page = driver.page_source
driver.quit()
soup = BeautifulSoup(page, 'html.parser')
```

Hope you'd find this useful. I also used it more comprehensively [here](https://github.com/odunayo12/web-crawl/blob/963b7430358641001127630d9e21ce8535174e33/asset_script/bachelor.py#L28).